# Can Java Preference API be used as an alternaitve to avoid reading File?

Tags: java, swing, preference

In my program there's requirement to read file content at the time of program startup. Right now file is loaded in the constructor. Since file is a bit huge and I/O is being performed so it takes a bit of time to show screen.

My question is, can I use Preference API as an aternative of file I/O? Since content is not changed frequently so I want to avoid I/O unless it's asked by user. I would like to load content once if preference not set and as long as preference is not empty it fetches content from Preference rather than file.

Share your thoughts.

Comment: What's in this file, and what exactly do you mean by "startup"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Zhedar's [point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25663111/230513) about `Preferences` is well taken. Instead, load the file in the background using [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25526869/230513). With suitable granularity in `publish()` and `process()`, results can begin appearing immediately. The GUI will remain responsive while the remainder of the file loads.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it wouldn't make a difference if performance matters.
A `Preference` is nothing but a file on your disk, too. In fact on `UNIX` and `Mac OS X`-Computers it would be saved in an `XML`-File, `Windows` puts `Preference`s  in the `registry`. You may look in the wrong direction here.
*Is your file that big*? **Then don't load it in the main thread.**
To achieve that, do long running IO-Operations in a different thread and show a loading screen or something like that instead. Since you don't said which UI technology you use I cannot provide any specific information to achieve that. If you're using swing I recommend you to take a look into the `SwingWorker` class.

Comment: I am using Swing and GUI is actually part of OpenOffice Plugin