# How to load large text file in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, large-files

I want to load large text file quickly in a `JTextArea` using Swing components. I tried to load a 100MB file, and it loads within seconds. But when I try to load more than a 200MB file, it takes more than 5 minutes.

How can I load large data files? For reading I use a `BufferedReader` and to display I use the `setText()` method from `JTextArea`.

Comment: see possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25526833/2587435)

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25526869/3755692) answer

Comment: Already I tried with SwingWorker also.But,It results same.That's why I asked question again.Thank you for reply.Please try it.

Comment: are you setting line by line or whole text at once?

Comment: I read the line by line using BuffereedReader and store in StringBuilder reference then it convert into String text.Then I use   textArea.setText(String text) method.