# Optimize data calling in JDBC onto JTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, jtable

currently I have data in MySQL server and I am calling the datas onto the JTable through JDBC. However there are 1369 rows and it seems that it has too much data for it to load. It usually takes 5 minutes to load. Are there anyways to optimize the process? This is my code(I apologize in advance for a messy code):

```
public class DataTable {
private String databaseName = "*****";
private String tableName = "******";
public void showDatabase(){
    Connection conn = null;
    DatabaseMetaData meta = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    int k = 0;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + databaseName;
        String connectionUser = "*****";
        String connectionPassword = "*****";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPassword);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        meta = conn.getMetaData();
        dataSets(stmt, meta);


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        try { if (rs != null) rs.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        try { if (stmt != null) stmt.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        try { if (conn != null) conn.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}

//return the column size of the table
public int getColumnNumber(DatabaseMetaData meta, Statement stmt) throws SQLException
{
    //ResultSet rs = meta.getColumns(null, null, "practiceexample", null);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName);
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    return columnsNumber;
}


//return the rowNumber of the tables
public int getRowNumber(Statement stmt) throws SQLException
{
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tableName);
    int rowCount = 0;
    while(rs.next()){
        rowCount = rs.getInt(1);
    }

    return rowCount;
}

public void dataSets(Statement stmt, DatabaseMetaData meta) throws SQLException
{
    String[] columnNames = new String[getColumnNumber(meta, stmt)];
    String[][] dataSets = new String[getRowNumber(stmt)][columnNames.length];


    ResultSet column = meta.getColumns(null, null, tableName, null);

    int i = 0;
    while(column.next())
    {
        columnNames[i] = column.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
        //columnNames.add(i, column.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
        i++;
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < dataSets.length; j++)
    {
        String[] singleRowData = new String[columnNames.length]; 
        ResultSet data = null;
        for(int k = 0; k < columnNames.length; k++)
        {
            String columnName = columnNames[k];
            data = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT " + columnName + 
                    " FROM " + tableName + " LIMIT " + j + ", " + 1);
            while(data.next())
            {
                singleRowData[k] = data.getString(columnName);
            }

        }

        dataSets[j] = singleRowData;
    }


    SimpleTable table = new SimpleTable(columnNames, dataSets);
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            table.createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}

class SimpleTable{
    String[] columns;
    String[][] dataSets;

    public SimpleTable(String[] columns, String[][] dataSets){
        this.columns = columns;
        this.dataSets = dataSets;
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI(){
        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3, 3));

        final JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(dataSets, columns));
        final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED
                , JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        Dimension dimension = table.getPreferredSize();
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(dimension.width, table.getRowHeight() * 30));

        JPanel navigation = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        JButton next = new JButton(">");
        next.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                int height = table.getRowHeight() * (20-1);
                JScrollBar bar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
                bar.setValue(bar.getValue() + height);
            }
        });

        JButton previous = new JButton("<");
        previous.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                int height = table.getRowHeight()*(20-1);
                JScrollBar bar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
                bar.setValue( bar.getValue()-height );
            }
        } );

        navigation.add(previous);
        navigation.add(next);

        gui.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        gui.add(navigation, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
    }
}


}
```

Comment: A way to optimize your whole app will be by using a connection pool instead of creating physical database connections manually. This will incredibly enhance your app.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still new to this and I'm not quite sure what the connection pool is. Is that in a java library?

Comment: You could use a `SwingWorker` to load the data in the background and push updates to the UI. While it won't speed up the entire process, it will allow you to present the UI much earlier, giving the illusion of speed

Comment: This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25526869/230513) may help.

Comment: Thank you for the help everybody. I was able to figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO the root of the bad permormance is you unnecessarily query the database mutliple times to get the data (columns, rows, rows number, columns number, etc) you need:

To get columns number:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName);
```

To get rows number:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tableName);
```

To get rows (this is the worst beacuse it's inside a loop):

```
data = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT " + columnName + " FROM " + tableName + " LIMIT " + j + ", " + 1);
```

### How to solve it

Just query the database once. A single [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData--) and its associated [ResultSetMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) should be enough to accomplish your goal. Additionaly, and as already suggested, use a `SwingWorker` to do database calls in a separate thread. For example:

```
final JTable table = new JTable();

SwingWorker<Void, TableModel> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, TableModel> () {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName);
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();

        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount(); // columns number
        String[] columnNames = new String[columnCount];
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            columnNames[i] = metaData.getColumnName(i); // fill columns names
        }

        resultSet.last();
        int rowCount = resultSet.getRow(); // get rows number
        resultSet.beforeFirst();

        Object[][] data = new Object[rowCount][columnCount];
        int currentRow = 0;
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            for (int currentColumn = 1; currentColumn <= columnCount; currentColumn++) {
                data[currentRow][currentColumn - 1] = resultSet.getObject(currentColumn); // fill data set
             }
             currentRow++;
        }

        TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        publish(model);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<TableModel> chunks) {
        TableModel model = chunks.get(0);
        table.setModel(model);
    }
}

worker.execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried that and it gives me an error because I need to return Void type function. I am clueless on why that is.

Comment: Actually I figured it out! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Oh, I forgot to `return null` at the end of `doInBackground()` implementation. This is because SwingWorker<V,T> is designed to be highly reusable (by using Generics) and let the implementers tell the type returned by `doInBackground()` method (by contract it must return something): this is what V means. This value is internally available through `get()` method. OTOH parameter T represents the class' managed by `publish` and `process` methods. So in this case you don't have to return nothing but `null` because `get()` is never used (rarely it is). @Kito