# Pre-render panels in Swing

Tags: java, swing

In my application, the first time a panel gets displayed, there is noticeable UI lag in displaying it. Every time after the first, it is displayed fast and there is no lag.

I am assuming this is because it has to do its initial paint or whatever it does under the hood. Is there a way I can render/paint all my panels before showing them, such as during application start?

I am using a Card layout to show my panels like so:

```
public void showCard(final String card) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) window.getContentPanel().getLayout();
                layout.show(window.getContentPanel(), card);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling the JFrame pack method somewhere?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc No, I am not

Comment: Avoid blocking the event dispatch thread, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25526869/230513).

Comment: @trashgod Would my results suggest that I am blocking the EDT somewhere in my code?

Comment: I could be wrong; [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) to be sure.