# Trying to use SwingWorker in Search program that uses FileVisitor in a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker, filevisitor

This continues [this thread of August 16, 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32040032/searching-thousands-of-files-via-a-thread-and-tree-walker-writing-matches-to)

I'm modifying my `Search` program to use `SwingWorker`. The original code (`main` shown below) has one `Thread` that is invoked in `main` and "walks the file tree" from a given node:

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          gui = new GUI();
          Utilities.disable(GUI.btnStop);
        }});   
     t = new Thread(new TASK());
     taskStarted = false;
  }
}
```

Here's the original class header for `TASK`:

```
public class TASK extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> implements Runnable{
```

But in order to use `SwingWorker`, (I assume) I need `TASK extends SwingWorker`, making the original `run` command illegal (error: `run` is `final` in `SwingWorker`).

Here's original `run`:

```
  public void run() 
  {
      SearchyGUI.disposition = FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
      Files.walkFileTree(path , this);
  }
```

Since I can't use `run`, I made the code above the initialization for class `TASK` like so:

```
public class TASK implements SwingWorker implements FileVisitor<Path> {
  public void TASK() 
  {
      System.out.println("Here we are starting TASK...");
      SearchyGUI.disposition = FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
      Files.walkFileTree(path , this);
  }
```

But now the line in `main` below causes error (no suitable constructor since now TASK doesn't implement runnable....):

```
 t = new Thread(new TASK());
```

And if I just say `new TASK();` the GUI shows, but when I click the Search button, nothing happens. No file walk. No errors. The output from `TASK` doesn't even show. So no chance to invoke `SwingWorker`. (In fact, just to see what might happen [nothing] I removed it from the class header for `TASK`: `public class TASK /*extends SwingWorker*/ implements FileVisitor<Path>`.)

If anything obvious is wrong, I'd love to see it. If not, I will spend a good long while making a `SSCCE`.

Comment: I would create a SwingWorker class that doesn't implement FileVisitor but rather that uses a FileVisitor by composition, i.e., that contains a FileVisitor instance. And don't create `new Thread(...)`. Instead you create your SwingWorker instance and call `execute()` on it.

Comment: Did so, and, after not so long, I got output! But since I haven't implemented the `doInBackground` and `process` (etc.) methods, it's clunky. **BUT** thanks to your single sentence, I got the job to the next phase. THANKS, as always! (This comment was a lot older; I forgot to Add Comment for many minutes!)

Comment: Yes, activate your visitor from within the doInBackground method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Hover, I have a reasonably-smooth-working Search program. Highlights (i.e., no details about variables or logic):

```
public class Main  
{
  public static void main(String args[]) 
  {
    EventQueue.invokeLater
    (
      new Runnable() 
      {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
          gui = new GUI();
        }
      }
    );
  }
}

//==============================================================

public class GUI extends JFrame
{
  private static void btnSearchActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
  {
      TASK task = new TASK();
      task.execute();      
  }
}

//==============================================================

public class TASK extends SwingWorker<Void,String>
{
  FV fv;

  TASK()
  {
    fv = new FV();
  }

  //-------------- inner class   

    class FV implements FileVisitor<Path>
    {
      public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path f, BasicFileAttributes a) throws IOException 
      {
        if(f.getFileName().toString().toLowerCase().matches(fPatt.toLowerCase().trim()))
        {
             publish(s); // old --> report(f); -- see process method below
        }
        return Main.disposition;
      }
    }

  //----------------

  protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception 
  {
    Files.walkFileTree(path, fv);
    return null;
  }

// **EDIT** added new method

  @Override
  protected void process(List<String> chunks){
    for (int i = 0; i < chunks.size(); i++) {
      report(chunks.get(i));
    }
  }


}
```

Only thing troubling me is that I haven't implemented the `publish` and `process` and other `SwingWorker` methods.

*EDIT*

So I included the two in the code above.

**EDIT 2**

I changed types on several statements, based on the class definition for `TASK`:

`public class TASK extends SwingWorker<Void,String>`

The first generic type parameter for `SwingWorker`, which is `Void` above, must be the type returned by `doInBackground` (and `get`, if used).

The second, `String` above, must be the type used in `publish` and `process`.

Comment: No need for the invokeLater and Runnable in your `btnSearchActionPerformed` method as it should already be called on the EDT.

Comment: Thanks. It was there out of earlier desperation. I've added `publish` and `process`. Not sure of any differences in operation.

Comment: Actually, `invokeLater`, etc. were there more out of ignorance than desperation. Desperation because something else was preventing proper execution; ignorance because ... they were there unnecessarily and I didn't know it.