# JFrame: Log window WITH tabs/columns?

Tags: java, swing, logging, jframe

I've researched on creating log displays in JFrame recently, but I would also like it to include tabs, and possibly be able to scroll. Would this be easy to implement, or would this be complicated?

I'm wanting something like this:

[image: TortoiseSvn client log window.]

Eventually, I would also like this to be scale-able, so I can include options, etc. on the screen (this log message would be in the lower right quadrant maybe). Thank you.

Comment: *"include tabs,.."*  See `JTabbedPane` *"..and possibly be able to scroll."* See `JScrollPane`. *"Would this be easy to implement, or would this be complicated?"*  Easy for me, cannot say how easy for you.  But go to your favorite search engine and add 'how to use' before each of those keywords (the class names) and you should end up at the Swing tutorial at Oracle.

Comment: thank you, I've found out about JTable! And it looks pretty great.

Comment: This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25526869/230513) works in the background.

Comment: *"I've found out about JTable!"*  D'Oh!  I was wondering why you mentioned tabs when showing a table!  :P  I figure now that by 'tabs' you meant the 'column header'.  In any case, glad you were able to find the right component for the requirement.  :)