# Using SwingWorker to show a loading animation

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, swingworker

**My Problem:**

I have a long executing task in my application (Needs to fetch data from the web), and I'm trying to display a loading screen with an animation (Just a rotating circle, no progress bar needed) while the task is being executed

**What I have done so far:**

I created the design for the loading screen in a panel and added it to a JFrame and tried to call instantiate the JFrame before the the code for the long process, and then dispose it after the process is done, like this:

```
LoadingFrame frame = new LoadingFrame();
//Long Process 
Wiring wiring = new Wiring(node.source); 
wiring.generateScopeForTargetNode();
// close() calls setVisible(false) and then dispose()
frame.close();
```

However, the frame did not get repainted until the task was done and all I received was a blank box, and in the end it didn't get disposed.

I searched SO for the problem, and found that it has to do with Threads and concurrency (Which I am unfamiliar with) and found suggestions to use `JDialog` instead of `JFrame`, so I followed the suggestion. What I ended up with is this:

- The JDialog loads and gets painted but the animation does not play
- The JDialog does not get disposed at the end

**What I need Help with:**

I have tried to search more for the problem and found suggestions that I should use `SwingWorker` to run one task in a thread and the animation in another if I have understood correctly. However I am unfamiliar with threads and with `SwingWorker` and need help in creating a simple `SwingWorker` instance that achieves what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) "to fetch data from the web" in the background. `publish()` interim results as they arrive. Your implementation of `process()` can then safely update a view component's model on the event dispatch thread. With even modest granularity, the user will start seeing data instead of an uninformative animation. This complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25526869/230513) updates the `TableModel` of a listening `JTable`, but the `Document` of a listening `JTextComponent` would work as well.