# JTable throws Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on some queries

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

I am using MySQL's sakila database to test my code. I have a JTable that I use for showing the results from the Views. Some work fine and others throw this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16 >= 16
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:648)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2717)
    at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5706)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCell(SynthTableUI.java:683)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCells(SynthTableUI.java:580)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paint(SynthTableUI.java:364)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.update(SynthTableUI.java:275)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:780)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:728)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JSplitPane.paintChildren(JSplitPane.java:1047)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1579)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1502)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

The code I am using to build the model is:

```
private void insertViewData(DataSet dataSet) {

    //testUpdateJTable2();

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Object[] headers = null;
            Object[][] data = null;
            try {
                List<String> tmp = dataSet.getColumnNames();
                headers = (String[]) tmp.toArray(new String[tmp.size()]);
                data = dataSet.toArray();
                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, headers) {

                    @Override
                    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                        return false; //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                    }

                };
                tblData.setModel(model);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                String messageString = e.getMessage();
            }

            tblData.invalidate();
            tblData.revalidate();
            tblData.repaint();
        }
    });

}
```

An example of the data returned from one of the queries that has the error is:

```
"Woodridge,Australia", "Jon Stephens", 33726.77
"Lethbridge,Canada", "Mike Hillyer", 33679.7
```

Comment: No exception is caught.

Comment: What does the debugger show?

Comment: Just the exception above

Comment: The last three lines are superfluous; updating the model should cause the listening table to update itself; verify that `dataSet` is not changing behind your back.

Comment: I removed those lines thanks @trashgod. I made a simple tablemodel and have found that for some reason the SynthTableUI class is getting the wrong row count. I have to figure out why. It seems that getRowCount isn't hit for the size.

Comment: Sounds like incorrect synchronization; maybe try `SwingWorker`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25526869/230513).

Answer (score 0):

It ended up that another spot in my code that I thought was no longer there was setting a row sorter. So I added code to remove sorting.

Comment: How did u do that ?