# Can we update a table on a thread before adding it to the GUI?

Tags: java, multithreading, jtable

I know that you should never modify a SWING component on a thread other than the EDT. What if I have a JTable object that I have created using the code:

```
JTable myTable = new JTable(myTableModel);
```

but I have not yet added the table to any SWING component. Can I call the JTable methods on a thread in such a case? For example I set up the size, foreground and background colors, column widths, and some other stuff. Can all of this be done on a thread other than the EDT if the table has not been added to the GUI?

Comment: You create the JTable and add it to the Swing GUI on the Event Dispatch thread.  No exceptions.  You mayupdate your table model in a separate thread, while you're constructing the GUI in the EDT, as long as you pass the table model instance to the JTable when you're creating the GUI.

Comment: To clarify @GilbertLeBlanc's comment: you may `publish()` updates destined for your `TableModel` on a separate thread as long as you `process()` them on the EDT, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25526869/230513).

Comment: Ok thanks. It's clear now.