# Java MVC pattern

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I'm trying to build a desktop application in Java using Swing. Right now I have developed a program which doesn't have any user interface. Essentially what my program does is, it takes a file which contains timeseries data as an input, and produces that data as audio to the user. I have got 7 classes that modify the input data. My question is, how do I use the MVC pattern on this project? I have several different objects, that are handled in various ways, how do I translate it to one model object? It is confusing to me, since all the MVC example codes have been really simple and only use one class for each part.

This is pretty much how my project is structured:

1) Data is read from a file

2) That data is transformed into a list of segment objects

3) Those segments are sonified (made into a .midi file)

4) The midi file is played to the user.

Hope this question wasn't too confusing and you can help me out. Thanks!

Edit: I have several classes such as PerformSegmentation and PerformSonification which manipulate Segment objects and create new Midi objects. Should all those classes be part of the Model layer?

Comment: I use this [pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25526869/230513) to collect data in the background.

Comment: Often, your MVC "Model" is more of a DTO that you can then transform into your internal structures arbitrarily.