# How do I dynamically update JTable in View Observer?

Tags: model-view-controller, jtable

I have a `View` class that is an `Observer` of a `Model`. The view class has an `Update()` method which receives an array whenever that array is updated. I have verified the array is received, after which a new table model is created and applied  to the JTable using the `setModel()` method.

The problem is, the table view is not visibly refreshed until the controller's file processing loop *ends*.

My goal is to have the table view be updated in realtime (dynamically), whenever its underlying data model is updated.

Comment: Update the table's `TableModel` on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), and the listening `JTable` will update itself in response.

Comment: @trashgod - To further clarify, what you're saying is table refresh is implicitly triggered in response to the model update, but that update is blocked by the action handler's thread. A common type of problem. Same kind of thing occurs with tables in iOS

Comment: @HotAppleCyber: Good point; a `SwingWorker`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25526869/230513), may be warranted.

Comment: Good point (and nice solution, btw :) )